# Data synchronization between mysql and mongodb databases

Tags: mysql, mongodb, synchronization

My application's primary database is `MySQL` and I use `MongoDB` as a buffer/secondary database.

So when there is a save/update operation in the MySQL, for certain cases, some part of the data is also pushed into the Mongo datbase.

The problem that I am facing is that after I try the save/update operation in MySQL, if the later insert/update operation into the MongoDB failed, I don't have way to bring it back in sync.

Is there a way by which I can achieve this synchronization ?

Answer (score 1):

If your application can tolerate the delay in update to mongodb, push a message to some QUEUE process and have a listener which does retries to save it to mongodb.
All implementation depends on language and frameworks you are using.

Comment: The application is in python. The insert/update usually happens properly, but I'm thinking for a fail safe, just in case the operation fails and a way to bring it back in sync.